# HABTM query with condition from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Friendship class in my Rails application. I use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association for connect `Users`. My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :friends,
                            class_name: "User",
                            join_table: :friends,
                            foreign_key: "user_id",
                            association_foreign_key: "friend_id"
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum status: [:requested, :received ,:accepted]
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I tried to get a friends with `status: :accepted`, but Rails uses search this condition for `User` model:

```
@friends = @user.friends.where(status: :accepted)

ERROR:  column users.status does not exist
LINE 1: ...s"."friend_id" WHERE "friends"."user_id" = $1 AND "users"."s...
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friends" ON "users"."id" = "friends"."friend_id" WHERE "friends"."user_id" = $1 AND "users"."status" = 'accepted'
```

How can i create a correct query?

Comment: It would be better to use a has_many :through association and store the status in the join model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. We can use a status index for this query. All enum statuses with indexes stored in `Classname.enumnames[]`:

```
@friends = @user.friends.where(friends: {status: Friend.statuses[:accepted]})
```

Answer (score 0):

since you use `join_table`, you need to specify the table name

from `@user.friends.where(status: :accepted)`

to `@user.friends.where('friends.status': :accepted)`

Comment: It's steel making querry with NULL status. I'm found a solution